# Apache poi multiple Doughnut Chart in XSSFClientAnchor

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am writing a code which creates multiple DoughnutChart in excel file.I can create multiple doughnut Chart and put them side by side using multiple anchore.
Now i have two issues

1. Values are not displayed on the DoughnutChart.
2. Every single anchore has its own border. For multiple chart i need to use multiple Anchore.I dont want those chart seperated by borders.My task is all the charts should be side by side and one single border no seperation.And I think it might not possible to create multiple chart in a single anchore.

public String picChart7() throws IOException {

```
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("doughnutChart");
        sheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);
        final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 2;
        final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

        XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor1 = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 4, 28);
        anchor1.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
        anchor1.getTo().setCol(4);
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor2 = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 7, 28);
        anchor1.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

        XSSFChart chart1 = drawing.createChart(anchor1);
        chart1.setTitleText("chart1");
        chart1.setTitleOverlay(false);
        //chart1.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.TOP);

        XSSFChart chart2 = drawing.createChart(anchor2);
        chart2.setTitleText("chart2");
        chart2.setTitleOverlay(false);
        //chart2.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        
        XDDFChartLegend legend1 = chart1.getOrAddLegend();
        legend1.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);

        XDDFChartLegend legend2 = chart2.getOrAddLegend();
        legend2.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);
        
        //{1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.6,8.5,9.5};
        String[] stringArray1 = new String[]{"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};
        XDDFDataSource<String> stringValue1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(stringArray1);
        Long[] longArray1 = new Long[]{ 11L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L };
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Long> longValue1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(longArray1);

        String[] stringArray2 = new String[]{"one","two"};
        XDDFDataSource<String> stringValue2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(stringArray2);
        Long[] longArray2 = new Long[]{ 60L,40L };
        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Long> longValue2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(longArray2);
        
        XDDFDoughnutChartData data1 = new XDDFDoughnutChartData(chart1, chart1.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewDoughnutChart());
        data1.setVaryColors(true);
        data1.setHoleSize((short) 50);
        data1.setFirstSliceAngle(10);

        XDDFDoughnutChartData data2 = new XDDFDoughnutChartData(chart2, chart2.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewDoughnutChart());
        data2.setVaryColors(true);
        data2.setHoleSize((short) 50);
        data2.setFirstSliceAngle(10);
        
        XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data1.addSeries(stringValue1, longValue1);
        XDDFChartData.Series series2 = data2.addSeries(stringValue2, longValue2);

        // Do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
        
        // Data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in Calc
        int pointCount1 = series1.getCategoryData().getPointCount();
        for (int p = 0; p < pointCount1; p++) {
            chart1.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
            chart1.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
                    .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(getColor(p));//get custom coloring
        }
        int pointCount2 = series2.getCategoryData().getPointCount();
        for (int p = 0; p < pointCount2; p++) {
            chart2.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
            chart2.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
                    .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(getColor(p));//get custom coloring
        }
        
        chart1.plot(data1);
        chart2.plot(data2);

        // Write the output to a file
        try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("picChart7.xlsx")) {
            wb.write(fileOut);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my code.It creates an excel file with multiple doughnut chart. Please let me know if you dont understand my question.I am new to Apache POI.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display values in segments of a pie or doughnut chart, settings for data labels must be set in chart.

Let it be `XSSFChart chart` and chart be a doughnut chart, then:

```
// Add data labels
if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) {
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
}
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
```

And to remove the border around the chart space code like so:

```
// chart area (chartspace) without border line
chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();
```

This sets a line having no fill as shape property to the chart space.

Complete example usable using current Apache POI 5.2.4.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDoughnutChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.DefaultIndexedColorMap;

public class DoughnutChartsXDDF {
    
  static XSSFChart createDoughnutChart(XSSFSheet sheet, String[] categories, Number[] values, String titleText, int col1, int row1, int col2, int row2) {
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, col1, row1, col2, row2);

    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    chart.setTitleText(titleText);
    chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
    XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);

    XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories);
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Number> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values);

    XDDFDoughnutChartData data = (XDDFDoughnutChartData)chart.createData(ChartTypes.DOUGHNUT, null, null);
    data.setVaryColors(true);
    data.setHoleSize(50);
    XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(cat, val);
    chart.plot(data);

    // Do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
    if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
    chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

    // Data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in Calc
    int pointCount = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount(); 
    for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
        .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(DefaultIndexedColorMap.getDefaultRGB(p+10));
    }
    
    // Add data labels
    if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
    }
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);    
    
    // chart area (chartspace) without border line
    chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();

    return chart;
  }   
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("doughnutChart");
      
      String[] categories = new String[]{"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};
      Number[] values = new Number[]{ 11L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L };
      XSSFChart chart1 = createDoughnutChart(sheet, categories, values, "Doughnut-Chart 1", 0, 4, 4, 20);

      categories = new String[]{"one","two"};
      values = new Number[]{ 60L,40L };
      XSSFChart chart2 = createDoughnutChart(sheet, categories, values, "Doughnut-Chart 2", 4, 4, 8, 20);
       
      // Write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-doughnut-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Axel Richter . Your solution works for me. Thank you.